# Host-only network adapter (enp0s8) not starting on boot in CentOS7

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox, route

I've installed CentOS7 in virtual box. I've 2 network cards - one host-only (vboxnet0) adapter `enp0s8` (which I want to be static) and the other the NAT adapter `enp0s3`. The host-only adapter never comes active on boot and I've to always run `ifup` to bring it up. NAT is active on boot.

I've already added `ONBOOT="yes"` in  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8`. The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8` is given below:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.56.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s8
UUID=451a1700-6a0f-430a-b5ac-96fe2bf748b3
DEVICE=enp0s8
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
#PEERDNS="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
#IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV4_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="b5ee8854-996e-44dc-9548-f6a1f1afa3b2"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
ONBOOT="yes"
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DNS3=192.168.0.1
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I know I am late to this party. I had a similar problem with a host-only adapter in Centos7.  It turned out that the Mac address in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8 (HWADDR="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx") was different to that shown in the VirtualBox GUI (Centos7-> Settings-> Network -> Adapter2 -> Advanced -> Mac address). Got the inspiration when reading your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Host-only interface from enp0s8 to enp0s9. Enp0s8 is innet always, enp0s9 is the host-only. It will work.